# How to get an image sent from a servlet with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I am trying to send a string to be encoded in a qr image and return the image on the same page.

```
<form action="qrservlet" method="get">
    <p>create QR Code</p>
        <input type="text" name="qrtext" />     
        <input type="submit" value="Generate QR Code" />        
    </form>
```

This works fine but it returns a new page. I'm trying to load the image in the page itself.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",                        
            url: "qrservlet",
            data: { "qrtext" : "www.mypage.com" },
            success:function(result)
            {
                $("#content").html(result);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

When I try this it returns a bunch of symbols.

Here is my servlet

```
String qrtext = request.getParameter("qrtext");

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = QRCode.from(qrtext).to(
                ImageType.PNG).stream();

        response.setContentType("image/png");
        response.setContentLength(out.size());

        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

        outStream.write(out.toByteArray());

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
```

Comment: and how does a QR code looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the image url from the AJAX request.

Than use the below code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "qrservlet",
            data: {
                "qrtext": "www.mypage.com"
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#content").html('<img src="'+result+'" >'); //changed here
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm still pretty new to ajax, what do you mean return the url? Is the returned url not in result?

Comment: Would I need to edit my servlet on how it sends? I guess my real problem is I'm not quite getting how the form works so easy and the ajax call is returning the weird symbols. Even with adding the image tag

Comment: @user2780385 yes you need to edit your servlet ,and set it to return image url .

Comment: When I use the form this is the url that is returnedmaypage/qrservlet?qrtext=www.yahoo.com

Comment: But this won't work if the image is stored into a local filesystem, let's say the path = "C:\myLocalDirectory\myImage.png" 
      $("#content").html(<img src="'+ path +'" >)
 doesn't show the image.

Answer (score 0):

To display an image you will need an img-tag in html. What an img-tag will do in order to display that image is to get the data from the server. This leads to the fact, that there's no need to do the typical ajax call to the server and then display the result, but you just render the img-tag into your document:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
       $("#content").html('<img src="qrservlet?qrtext=www.mypage.com" />');
    });
});
```